# Excel variables X values

Tags: excel, graph

I have two working days dates, first_date, second_date.

I have a data table with decreasing working date:

second date         value 1

second date - 1     value 2

second date - 2     value 3

....                ....

firstdate           value n

firstdate -1        value n + 1

...                 ...

(Data table doesn't stop at first date).

I want to plot all values between first and second date, only for working days.

I've found some ways with a macro, but I want it to be automated.

It's easy to calculate the number of line with =NETWORKDAYS(firstdate,seconddate), but I can't manage to type this function into the series X/Y values.

I have something like ='sheet1!$D$4:$D$33.

I want something like ='Sheet1'!$D$4:$D$  &  NETWORKDAYS(firstdate,seconddate)

Someone know how to type that ?

I've tought about putting NETWORKDAYS(firstdate,seconddate) in a cell and use the cell.value in the formula. How does it works ?

Comment: `Networkdays` computes the number of work days, but if your data range in column D still contains non-working days, using this in your Series formula is not likely to yield the desired result.

Comment: My column D only contain working days.

Comment: I suggest using Named Ranges which can be set using formulas to be dynamic. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OFFSET` function to define a dynamic Named Range.  This Name can then be used in the series formula.

In my example I have the start_date and end_date in cells D1 & E1 respectively (if not, modify the formula as necessary).

**Step 1** Open the Name Manager, add a new name like "Workdays_Data" and in the Refers To: box, put the formula:

`=(OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$4,0,1,NETWORKDAYS(Sheet1!$D$1,Sheet1!$E$1),1))`

[image: Name Manager Dialog Box]

Then close the Name Manager dialog.

**Step 2** Select the data series, and in the formula bar, replace the range that refers to the Values with the new Name, `Workdays_Data`.  The part you need to modify is highlighted:

[image: Screenshot of the formula bar before modify]

After you make the change, the formula bar should look like:

[image: Formula bar AFTER modify to use the Named Range]

If you do this, then the chart should update any time you change the **end date**.

With some additional tweaking to the Name definition, you could modify this to also account for a dynamic start date.  For example, you could replace the "0" in the Name formula with a Match function, so that the name formula reads:

`=(OFFSET(Sheet8!$D$4,MATCH(Sheet8!$D$1,Sheet8!$D$4:$D$11,FALSE)-1,1,NETWORKDAYS(Sheet8!$D$1,Sheet8!$E$1),1))`

You could then create another Name called `Weekdays_XValues` and use it for the category labels in the chart, so that those update as well:

`=(OFFSET(Sheet8!$D$4,MATCH(Sheet8!$D$1,Sheet8!$D$4:$D$11,FALSE)-1,0,NETWORKDAYS(Sheet8!$D$1,Sheet8!$E$1),1))`

The end result should be a fully dynamic chart based on the chosen start/end dates, like:

[image: Excel chart using dynamic named range for Values and XValues]

Comment: Thanks, this is working very well, though I've encountered a problem. My start date and end date can be out off the bound of my table. My guess is to make a dynamic table, it's not the same kind of problem. If you have a hint for me I would take it. If no I will probably post another question.

Comment: I could do this with a macro, but someone else can probably figure out how to do it with Formulas only. Perhaps post another question (and include a link to this so that others can build on what we have already done).  In the new question, explain how the chart would work if you chose an out-of-bounds start or end date.  If nobody can show you how to do it with formulas, I'll suggest how to do it with VBA.