# Updating a table with Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two working days dates, `first_date` and `second_date`.

I have a data table with decreasing working date:

```
second_date        value 1    
second_date - 1    value 2    
second_date - 2    value 3    
   ....             ....    
first_date         value n    
first_date -1      value n + 1    
   ....             ....
```

**The table doesn't stop after first date.**

I wanted to plot the value between first_date and second_date. I've found a way to dynamically choose the X/Y values: [Excel variables X values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042445/excel-variables-x-values/16047124?noredirect=1#comment22957934_16047124)

However, now I have another problem, when I choose a date out of the bound of my data table it doesn't plot what I've asked (which is normal). I would like to update my data table depending on my dates.

The dates in my data table are simply built: `=second_date` in the first row (`D4`), `=+WORKDAY(D4,-1)` in the second row, and I used the click and drags tool to build other rows recursively.

Is there a way to stop this recursion to my first date without VBA? How would you build such a table with only formulas?

Comment: Would it be preferable to **prevent** user from choosing an out of bounds date?  This can be done pretty easily I think using validation lists and another Named Range.

Comment: The goal of my spreadsheet is to report data depending on what the user asks. A restrictive approach is not what I need (of course there will be a strict lower and upper bound as I don't have data a long time ago or for the future.

Comment: A point I forgot: I have many columns of value, with some time consuming functions. I want a dynamic data table also because I don't want to build the 10 years historic when I only need 3 months of datas.

Comment: I am not trying to push you to one solution, but it will be easier to simply restrict the inputs to a valid range of dates, using methods (named range, validation list) that you are already familiar with.


**>>** Why would you want to allow selection of dates for which no data exists?

**>>** What is the desired behaviour if the user chooses a date out of bounds, e.g., choose 4/1/2013 for the start date, but the table only contains dates from 4/10/2013 onward.

Comment: I think I can handle out of bounds date easily with IIf formulaes. I will try different solution after implementing the dynamic data table. What bother me is how to build the dynamic data table.

Comment: still no hint on how to do it easily...

Comment: Typically you can use a Named Range defined with the `Offset`, `CountA`/`CountIf` formulas to define a table of variable size.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA the only way to generate the data dynamically that I can think would be to generate the data conditionally on falling inside the time frame set between the 2 dates. As you said you only require about 3 months data then the extra "empty" cells would not impact performance significantly.

Specifically change your formula from D5 onward to the following (assuming D4=second_date):

> =IF(IFERROR(WORKDAY(D4,-1)>=first_date,FALSE),WORKDAY(D4,-1),#N/A)

Use a similar conditional logic to generate your values in the second column. You want to make sure that if the date condition is not met that it outputs an #N/A value. This is important when generating the graph (more on this below).

You can generate the graph initially as you would normally including the maximum dimensions of your table (for max 3 months: ~60 workdays). When you change the dates it will include the #N/A operator on dates outside your range. The graph will ignore these datasets as well as adapting the scale creating effectively a graph with only the date ranges the user wants.

If the inclusion of #N/A is a concern there is some further options. You can create conditional formatting that makes the font white for #N/A's for a cosmetic resolution. Or you can configure your chart to ignore empty cells and replace in the above formula "" for #N/A, achieving the same result.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if further clarification is required or if this does not meet your specific needs. Cheers